# How can i get the Complement of the filtered data using crossfilter

Tags: crossfilter

I am using crossfilter to filter data. Here is my code

```
var ndt=crossfilter(unique);
        var dimt=ndt.dimension(function(d){
            return d.etime;
        });
        var dimtd=dimt.filterFunction(function(d)
                {
            if(seconds(d.etime)<seconds(ctime)-100)
                {
                return d;
                }
                });
        var problemdata=dimtd.top(Infinity);
```

My question is how can i get the complement of problem data. Is there any function or shortcut way. My goal is to get
{unique}-{problemdata}. That means the rows in unique which are not in problemdata.

Comment: This is probably not a good use-case for Crossfilter. Just for the information of those who come after us :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Crossfilter's method called [crossfilter.remove()](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_remove).

> ## crossfilter.remove()
>
> Removes all records that match the current filters from this
>   crossfilter.